# Where does one find pronunciation, spelling, and phonetic rules in English for Italian?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, resources

In English, a native speaker learns to spell based on the way words sound. Correspondingly, one learns to pronounce a word based on its spelling, using phonetics. This involves rules learned when quite young, such as "I before E, except after C, or when sounded as A, as in neighbour or weigh." and the like. Most rules are simply absorbed as we grow up and obtain more vocabulary.

However, when learning another language, particularly as an adult, it can be more difficult to pick up these "rules" and it helps if they are explicitly stated somewhere. For example, in my Italian lessons, I have learned a couple, such as the "soft" G or C when followed by I (eg: *Giacomo* or *città*).

There must be many other grammatical rules such as these English and Italian examples. Does anyone know of such a list of rules for Italian, but in English so a beginner can understand?

Comment: Could this help?: 1) http://web.stanford.edu/~jrb/reference/italian.html 2)http://www.conversationexchange.com/resources/pronunciation/it/index.php?lg=en

Comment: If you wanted to go all in, you could try the wikipedia page on italian phonology (both links given by Josh are not completely correct, although they're probably fine for a beginner). The good news is that there aren't that many rules, as far as languages go. Be careful that there are several sounds in Italian that the English language lacks (for example the consonants /gn/ and /gl/, but also the short vowel /o/) and so you will probably need to practice them a bit.

Comment: Apologies for the double comment: a (maybe simpler) resource is the Italian wikibook https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Italian/Pronunciation

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are asking for pronunciation rules (definitely don't worry about those, or you will be like the Italian kids in school spending a morning on "shoe" and "snake") or if you are looking for spelling rules (look for ortografia in grammar sites online), like why we write "piace" and not "piacie".

Comment: these might help you a bit: a pdf http://www.atuttascuola.it/viale/italiano/prospetto_generale_grammatica.pdf  and a few other grammar rules https://scrittinediti.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/appunti-di-grammatica-italiana-1-ortografia/

Comment: Thank you to all who responded, and also to the corrections of spelling and tags in my question -- all very much appreciated! I have lots of resources to look at now ;-) If anyone else finds this question and its answers useful, please feel free to vote up my question as well as any answers you find helpful. Cheers! Mrs_MG

Comment: I am a bit confused by all the downvotes. Is there any particular reason why this question is considered unsuitable for this site? It sounds as a perfectly natural question for a language learner [Maybe I should make this a meta question but I thought that this way I'd get more visibility]

Comment: @DenisNardin: I also don't understand the reason of the downvotes.

Comment: @ Denis Nardin, not sure if its that's the reason, but requesting for resources its often a bit at the limit... not only for the italian section... we should discuss it a bit more in meta, i saw there was a discussion started already... do we make it a matter on how much effort to put into googling for resources... or something like that?

Comment: @Erik As far as I understand from Meta, it is considered wrong to ask for resources already listed in the apposite Meta page. But this is not the case, so I'm left wondering.

Comment: @Denis Nardin, you are right, but in other sections of stackexchange that  are disgustingly strict this would have been shut down from the beginning... I like that here things are much more relaxed, but there are questions on hold because of the ease of googling for the answer and I don't find this question much different in that respect. That said I think it still should be kept because of the resources in the comments, which should fit the rules

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: I sarted this discussion on Meta: http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/q/1249/707 . I would like to know the opinion of the community about this. So far, no many people have participated in the discussion.

Comment: Interestingly, none of the resources in the answers here are on the "list of resources" so how is my question off-topic? Where, then, should I have asked this question? Also, I asked about resources that were in English, whereas most of the relevant references on the "list of resources" are Italian only, and I was also unable to find resources *in English* on the topic that were suitable for my purposes, hence my question. If this is wrong, why simply downvote, rather than explain the issue to me? Seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Mrs_MG i would move the discussion on Meta at the link Charo gave in her last comment. As for the downvotes... its SE, cant put too much weight on those

Comment: This Wikipedia article has a bunch of information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography Another article also summarizes English orthography https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_orthography#Spelling-to-sound_correspondences

Answer (score 3):

I am hoping that as I learn to *read* Italian, that my *spelling* will necessarily improve as well, since I will understand the *phonetics* better, and when to use all the accent marks, etc. that we do not really have in English, because I will have seen them written over and over while I am hearing them.  If you can hear the words as you see them in writing, I am finding that my brain just begins 'sussing out' the rules behind the punctuation and spelling and punctuation. We are all different - but this is working for me.

1. I like **"Italian in 10 minutes a day"** by Bilingual Books. This is paperback book that I
   bought to start off with.  It has English phonetic spellings of the
   Italian words.  It is VERY basic, but I found it to be very helpful
   in 'reminding' me what the words should sound like.  I don't think
   it has much grammar in it, but I am trying to learn that with
   different books.
2. Also, I have found that the site below has been helpful. The accent
   is questionable, I think (I have no reference, really, to make a
   judgement on the Italian accent, but I have heard the English one)
   but it helps me **read** a sentence or two and **hear** it at the
   same time, so I am gradually becoming better with the phonetics. I think (but do not know) that the examples are sentences that are actually in usage on Italian sites.
   http://context.reverso.net/translation/italian-english/Pronuncia
3. Also, I use Google/Translate the same way.  While the translations
   and accent are suspect, it IS useful, and I have been building up my phonetic understanding of speaking and comprehension speed this way as well, since I can read
   and hear at the same time. I find that it is an easy way to learn, and my "out loud" reading is becoming more accurate.

   - On the FULL site, (not the mobile one)
     you can actually highlight one word out of a sentence, see
     alternative translations, (suggested, I guess by anyone who cares to
     do so), and hear one word of a phrase over and over if you wish. 
     The information that you can glean this way is interesting, in
     addition to being helpful in elementary phonetics.  You are presented with different information depending on whether you are translating FROM or TO Italian from the English, so I often reverse the process, just to see what happens.  Once I have refined and polished a sentence, I 'star' it, which saves it to a phrase book.  This phrasebook, in turn, syncs with my phone, so I can review things while I am out and about, or I can have it printed out for me as a pdf.

Here is a picture of the kind of phonetic spelling that **"Italian in 10 minutes a day"** has.
[image]

Comment: The worst of these “spellings” is _pool-yah_, but the whole idea of learning another language without leaving one's own is wrong.

Comment: @WalterTross  - I found those phonetic spellings to be VERY helpful in the beginning in learning how to 'read aloud' in my head.  One of the biggest problems I faced was mentally decoding the new phonetic rules  ~ how to pronounce what I was reading.  It took me a while to remember how ci was pronounced, for instance.   This book  helped me a great deal, & allowed my brain to reprogram itself.  Sometimes, I think that it is easy to forget what is was like to learn, from scratch, a totally new language.  We all learn differently.  In my case, I like to use a LOT of different approaches.

Comment: @WalterTross: «the whole idea of learning another language without leaving one's own is wrong». I agree wholeheartedly: it is impossible to to get an understandable (let alone fluent or native-like) pronunciation of a foreign language by trying to formulate it with the phonemes of one's own. And pronunciation is only the most blatant case. It would be like trying to learn to drive a car by looking where to fit it the bridles or how to feed it hay.